# The Observer pattern using the pulling mechanism

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I was wondering about the following implementation of

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object arg)
```

while I want to send to all of my observer and update using `notifyObserver()` I and passing a references to `this` the observer can use the `getters` from the subject to pull the information he wants.

What is the `arg` argument on the update method meant for?

Comment: @RBT `arg` is a parameter or group of parameters, as an additional option

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When implementing the Observer pattern, there are two main approaches to consider: the 'push' model and the 'pull' model.

In the 'push' model, the subject (i.e. the Observable) sends the observer on notification all the data it will need. The observer doesn't need to query the subject for information. In the 'pull' model, the subject merely notifies the observer that something happaned, and the observer queries the subject based to get the information it needs.

Let's discuss the pros and cons of both approaches:

**Push**

The main advantage of the 'push' model is lower coupling between the observer and the subject. The observer doesn't need to know anything about the subject in order to query it. If it needed to, we'd need to do one of the following: A- do downcasting on the side of the observer in order to invoke class-specific `get` methods on the subject. This is bad. B- make the `Observable` interface more class-specific, offering specific `get` methods, thus making the relationship between the observer and subject less general and making things more copupled.

By implementing the 'push' model, we avoid all of this.

However the disadvantage is less flexibility: the subject may not always know what exact information the observers need in order to send it to them. This will often mean more specific Observer intefaces, such as `AgeObserver` that are notified when the 'age' of the subject is changed, and `HeightObserver` which are sent the current `height` of the subject on notification.

This is one option. The other is the subject sending a whole lot of information encapsulated in an `Info` object of some sort and have the observers query it from there. But again, we can't be sure we're sending the correct info. So it's either this, or forcing the observers to implement more specific Observer interfaces, which tightens the coupling on the observer's side.

**Pull**

I already noted the disadvantages of the 'pull' model. The observers would have to know things about the subject in order to query the right information, which leads A- to downcasting (ugly), or B- favorably to more specific `Observable` interfaces, that offer more specific accessor methods. For example `AgeObservable` offers a `getAge()` method.

The advantage of this is more flexibility. Each observer can decide for itself what to query, without relying on the subject to send the correct information.

---

You should choose the strategy that is better for the specific project you're working on.

In reality, you'll always have specific `Observer` and `Observable` intefaces, so you have some coupling between the sides anyway.

So choose either 'pull' or 'push' by what fits you best.

Do all `AgeObserver`s need simply the `age` of the subject? Implement the 'push' model. Less coupling and simpler.

Do all `HeightObserver`s need varying information about the subject - aka one needs to query the age too, and some other object needs to query the weight in addition to the height? Implement the 'pull' model. This would force you to add accessors (getters) to the `Observable` inteface (either this or pass the actual object as a parameter in it's explicit type, but doing this through the interface allows you to deny the observers access to things that don't matter to them). This soultion creates higher coupling, but it's more flexible.

Choose what fits your situation best.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.
Regrading to my question , as you said while using pull , i need to down casting and using the getters , but what is the arg for in the observer update method?  - public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `Object arg` is meant for the 'push' model, where `arg` is an 'information bundle' sent to the observer.

Comment: Yeah this is what i was thinking as well , but then why do we send the obs ? :) if we down casting we can just pull the information that we need.

Comment: Are you talking about 'push' or 'pull'? The idea in 'push' is that the observer *doesn't need to know* about the type of the subject. Thus you avoid down-casting. Down-casting is mostly bad becasue it creates tighter coupling between the two sides - the observer now knows the exact type of the subject, which beats the whole purpose. What if later a new class implements the `Observable` interface? If you don't rely on the concrete type of the subject - i.e. by not doing down-casting - the current observer code will work just as well, polymorphically, with the new subject.

Comment: If your observer code relies on down-casting, it will need to change with every new class implementing the Observable interface, thus defeating the whole purpose of the pattern. This is an example of why 'programming to an interface, not a concrete implementation' is a good thing - code that works against an interface will work unchanged with every new class that implements the interface. If you rely on the concrete implementation - e.g. by doing downcasting, your code will need to change with every new Observable class. Beating the whole purpose.

Comment: So if you want to implement the 'pull' model - don't do down-casting! Instead, make a more specific Observable interface with getters. Like in my example: `AgeObservable` with a `getAge()` method. Then your observer code can talk to this interface without down-casting. This way it won't need to change with every new `AgeObservable` added to the program, allowing for extensibility and flexibility. The whole point of patterns such as Observer is acheving this flexibility.

Comment: In OO code, in general down-casting is a bad sign. 90% of the time you can replace it with a cooler, more elegant polymorphic solution.

Comment: Ok , cool i did not get yet my answer about the arg but you saved me many other questions , thank you!

Comment: My answer about the `arg` is that it's most probably the info object in the 'push' model. I don't know why you'd need it when pulling.